# can't open the page "127.0.0.1:8000" because the server dropped the connection unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run a Django project via Docker. I wrote a Dockerfile and docker-compose, but when I run the Django project it says :

*"Safari can't open the page
Safari can't open the page    "127.0.0.1:8000" because the server dropped the connection unexpectedly. This problem sometimes occurs if the server is busy.    Wait a few minutes and try again."*

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip wheel

COPY . .

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    invite_service:
        container_name: invite_service
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

**ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django settings**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0']
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

into

```
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

in your docker file.

As `127.0.0.1` this means it can only accept connections from within the container itself.

With `0.0.0.0`, you are specifying the django server bind to all available network interfaces, allowing it to be accessible from outside the container.

See [awesome-compose/django](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/django) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/blob/master/django/app/Dockerfile)